# Android RecognitionService License

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I am using Android Speech Recognition RecognitionService in Android API to build an app. Do I need to pay Google? Is there any number of transaction limitation? Is it totally free?

Comment: [RecognitionService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognitionService.html) is an abstract class to be used when you implement **your own** speech recognizer. You should clarify your question, explaining which component you are actually intending to use.

Comment: If you actually mean the [SpeechRecognizer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html) class, then yes, it's free to use, and AFAIK, there's no limitation.

Comment: Thanks Alexis Pigeon